# Interface Builder unable to determine type of storyboard

Tags: xcode, ios8, interface-builder

Gone through all the links on google and on here and a lot didn't have answers to them. I have an app that has a MainStoryboard.storyboard and a MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboard. The iPad storyboard opens fine. The "MainStoryboard.storyboard" throws the following error when I click on it in Xcode: "Interface Builder was unable to determine the type of "MainStoryboard.storyboard"." I cannot view or change the storyboard and it prevents the app from building. The build error is "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.InterfaceBuilder error 2001.)"

So here's what has happened on my end that I'm aware of in the past week. I was on Mavericks and the app built and ran just fine. I am in the middle of a move so I have not touched anything is 6 days. Today I installed Yosemite and upgraded Xcode to 6.1. I launched Xcode selected my storyboard, and these errors occurred.

I checked that the correct storyboard was chosen in build settings and it is.

I tried to rename the storyboard and duplicate it and that of course hasn't worked. I'm not sure if I screwed something up a week ago when I was working on it or if the upgrade to Yosemite messed something up or what. I've looked online and haven't really found any help. Other than reading the errors it throws, I'm not really sure what else to check either.

If anyone has help or has knows of things I can check to help further diagnose the issue I'd greatly appreciate it.

Here's screenshots of the errors.
http://i62.tinypic.com/21r02p.png
http://i60.tinypic.com/2r4txsw.png

P.S. I should mention I'm looking for solutions that don't require me to recreate the entire thing again. I could do that, but I am hoping that I can find a solution that won't be as time consuming. Hoping this is a "simple" issue to fix.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue and fixed it by deleting the file and reseting it in version control.

If your project isn't in version control you could try:

1. Copying the storyboard source
2. Removing the file from the project
3. Making a new storyboard with the same name
4. Pasting the old storyboard source into the new file

Comment: How do you delete the file and reset it in version control?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I edited my storyboard via a text editor and got the wrong set of double-quotes,if this is your case: it will be obvious when you open the storyboard file as source. (xml)

Then the last item/Controller you were working on, Delete (or edit if you're familiar with the xml layout) and it will load normally